# understand forecasts in linear state space models

Tags: r, time-series, state-space-models, dlm

The Kalman Filter provides the one-step-ahead forecasts within the recursions. We start estimating the (unkown) variance of the parameters for instance through `MCMC`  or `MLE`. Then we use the variance estimates (e.g. mean) to run the Kalman filter. But, since we have already used the data to estimate the variances, can we compute forecasts using the same data again? this is what I have understood the `dlmFilter` function from the `dlm` package does and would like to know why this is correct.